# Make compiler to tell what exact pure virtual methods make struct abstract?

Tags: c++

```
struct Base{
  virtual foo()=0;
  virtual bar()=0;
};
struct Derived:Base{
  virtual foo(){}
  //bar() is still pure virtual
};
static_assert(is_constructible_v<Derived>,"You forgot to override few methods: i do not know what are they.")
```

> *"i do not know what are they."*

How to replace this phrase with exact list of methods to be overridden?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was compiler support for putting a class's list of abstract methods into a string.

Comment: As soon as you try to instantiate `Derived` the compiler will tell you (at least g++ is showing the exact methods that are not overriden), not sure if it can be done with an assert.

Comment: What is the reason you want to do that with a `static_assert`, instead of letting the compiler to complain about `Derived:Base` being incomplete, when you try to instantiate it?

Comment: When I try in instantiate Derived with moke_shared it checks for is_constructible. And this is my point.

Comment: May be i need to simulate instantiation.

Comment: It's a compilation error in any case, and `is_constructible` can be false in other situations so your conclusion is wrong.

Comment: Please give some [mre] in your question and explain **what are your actual issue and motivations** and **what kind of software you are coding** (size, domain, operating system, compiler). We have to guess a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you simply need to ask the compiler to attempt a compile time instantiation. For example:

```
static_assert(sizeof(Derived[1]),"...");
```

Comment: https://tio.run/##dcxBCsIwEIXhfU4xdJWCtrq1uBFvISJjmspAbEJm2oUlZ4/F1o3g9ue9z4SwNQ77R84scTACJ2Q7KYCRogzoYPTUQue9Lo@75rffMS49NWr9n22k0baH/86U5lzXny8QAws5B2GI9jteOBQyN2S2UTTTy/pOr/hlfy03RVVVRdkoRb3AE6mHmZtSzm8

Comment: https://tio.run/##dcxBCsIwEIXhfU4xdNWCpro1uBFvISIxTWWgNiEzzcKQs8di60Zw@/PeZ7zfPowphThMhuGkySYBEDHwpAeIDjvonaub40799rsOS89KrP@zDRhtd/jvpDzntv18AQmIcRjAT8F@xwunGc1NE9nANeHLur5e8cv@2mwqKWXVKCFwZHhqHGHmUi7lDQ

Comment: Yes. This is what i am looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

> Make compiler to tell what exact pure virtual methods make struct abstract?

This is very compiler and tool specific.

If your C++ compiler is a *recent* [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) read its documentation (notably how to [invoke](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) it). Likewise for [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/).

> How to replace this phrase with exact list of methods to be overridden?

It might be not possible in standard [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) 11 (I am not sure: check by reading [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)). But you could customize your compiler (e.g. write your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html)) to warn you about such a situation.

Try also tools like the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) (with its FramaC++ variant), or customize them for your needs.

Consider generating C++ code for your needs (e.g. using [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or your own C++ metaprogram driven by the [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool you are using), like [SWIG](https://swig.org/) or [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/) do. The [Qt moc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html) tool could be inspirational, and perhaps could be useful to you or adaptable to your needs.